# Generative Adversarial Networks - The simplest possible examples

Tags: deep-learning, gan

I'm looking for the simplest possible examples of GANs. What would be simple yet illustrative examples with, say, univariate data and in which both the generator and the discriminator are as simple as possible (potentially depending only on one or two parameters each, and not necessarily being neural networks at all)? Thanks for your help!